# Angular2 show two decimals in input

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an angular2 app that needs to show ALWAYS two decimals in inputs after some calculations. But although in the component I force to have two decimals, in the input it shows it with zero decinmal, one decimal or the decimals that the number has but what I need is to show always two.

In the controller I force to have two decimals in this way

```
return +(this.getCost() * this.getQuantity()).toFixed(2);
```

But when I show that, the result can have different decimals size

```
<input name="number" pattern="^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?" step="0.01" formControlName="number" type="button" class="form-control" id="number" >
```

Adding that I;m using TypeScript and the field type is number (which I think is causing the rounded)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end I did't find the right answer...

What I did was to create the following function

```
fixDecimals(value : string){
    value = "" + value;
    value = value.trim();
    value = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
    return value;
  }
```

And I changed the input type to text (instead of number).

And I'm calling this function in the ngOnInit so, I'm always showing the number with to decimals to the user. The only pending thing is that if the user change the value and remove the decimals, the number won't be completed with the corresponding 00.

I tried with the onChange, but the prompt goes to the end of the input (which is very awkard for the user)

Answer (score 19):

I would suggest you to use a mask on the input field there is a package [text-mask](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/angular2#readme) that i've used before and works!

Note: take a look at you html input type, you said that is number, but actually in your question the type is button

To use the package:

1. Install the packages

   `npm i angular2-text-mask text-mask-addons --save`
2. Import it in you app-module file

   ```
   import { TextMaskModule } from 'angular2-text-mask';

   @NgModule({
     imports: [
       /* ... */
       TextMaskModule
     ]
     /* ... */
   })
   export class AppModule { }
   ```
3. In you component.ts

   ```
   import createNumberMask from 'text-mask-addons/dist/createNumberMask';

   @Component({   
     selector: 'app-my-component',   
     templateUrl: './my-component.html',   
     styleUrls: ['./my.component.scss'] }) 

     export class MyComponent implements OnInit { 
     public price = 0;

     private currencyMask = createNumberMask({
       prefix: '',
       suffix: '',
       includeThousandsSeparator: true,
       thousandsSeparatorSymbol: ',',
       allowDecimal: true,
       decimalSymbol: '.',
       decimalLimit: 2,
       integerLimit: null,
       requireDecimal: false,
       allowNegative: false,
       allowLeadingZeroes: false
     });

   }
   ```
4. In your component.html

   ```
   <input type="text" [textMask]="{mask: currencyMask}" name="receivedName" id="received" class="form-control" maxlength="50" [(ngModel)]="price"/>
   ```

Comment: This option sounds great... I was using the textmask for other things, but I didn't realize that I can use it for this... I will use your solution! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi! I'm trying this, but I'm getting this error:
InputComponent.html:12 ERROR TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function
    at n (textMaskCore.js:1)
    at n (textMaskCore.js:1)
    at Object.update (textMaskCore.js:1)
    at MaskedInputDirective.webpackJsonp.../../../../angular2-text-mask/dist/angular2TextMask.js.MaskedInputDirective.writeValue (angular2TextMask.js:48)
I tried with '' , 0, or [] as default vales but it is not working

Comment: @Faabass, could you solve your problem? If not can you create a small project with that error and push it to github? In that way i could validate what's going on!

Comment: I added my own answer, that was the best I can achieve... The mask solution sounded good, but didn't wotk as I expected

Comment: I confirm that this works as of `angular2-text-mask` v. 9.0.0 and `text-mask-addons` v. 3.2.7.

Comment: It still display `1`, but I want to be `1,00` displayed.

Comment: It works indeed. But, what if i want to make mathematical operations with the value?

Answer (score 6):

tl;dr; Option 1: return a string, don't convert to number. Option 2: Use a number pipe.

`toFixed` returns a string.

You are converting the result of `toFixed` to a number

```
return +(this.getCost() * this.getQuantity()).toFixed(2);
       ↑
```

When you convert `"1.20"` to a number it will "remove" the extra `0` returning `1.2`.

To show the result with 2 decimals you can return the result as a string so the `0` doesn't get cut off, or use a pipe.

You can use the [number pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe)

```
{{ 1.20 | number:'1.2-2' }}
```

Format: `{minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}`

- `minIntegerDigits` is the minimum number of integer digits to use. Defaults to 1.
- `minFractionDigits` is the minimum number of digits after fraction. Defaults to 0.
- `maxFractionDigits` is the maximum number of digits after fraction. Defaults to 3.

With the pipe you can keep your code returning a number and it will only change how the value is formatted when you show it on the screen.

Comment: You can use pipes anywhere in your template, but since you are binding the value with FromControl you will have to change that value to be a string so the `0` doesn't get cut off.

Comment: How can I use a template inside an input text?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if I understood the problem correctly but what I understood is you somehow want to force the input to contain two digits after decimal. Here is a try:
You need to convert the number to a float type and as you want it to be fixed to two decimal points use toFixed method.

```
Number.parseFloat(x).toFixed(2)
//Where x is the number which needs to be converted to a float type.
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If your input is inside a form with name: inputForm e.g

**HTML**

```
    <form [formGroup]="inputForm">
      <input name="number" (keyup)="fixNumber()" pattern="^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?" step="0.01" `enter code here`formControlName="number" type="button" class="form-control" id="number">
</form>
```

**TS**

```
public fixNumber(){

      let value =this.inputForm.get('number').value;
      let prefix:string = value.toString().split('.')[0];
      let suffix:string = value.toString().split('.')[1];
      if(suffix.length > 2){
        let suffix_subed = suffix.substr(0,2);
        let new_value = prefix+'.'+suffix_subed;
        this.inputForm.get('number').setValue(new_value);
      }
}
```

You may get some log erros, but i think that's not big dead for that workaround

Answer (score 1):

Use This Pipe

{{ number | number : '1.2-2'}}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, please highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar or using Ctrl+K on your keyboard to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

In angular 2 have [DecimalPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe) this will helpful to your requirement.Please Use it.
Sample:

```
Use format '3.2-5' : 

minIntegerDigits = 3 
minFractionDigits = 2 
maxFractionDigits = 5 

num = 12.324324

{{num1 | number:'3.2-5'}} 

012.63847
```

Comment: I believe the question is focused on inputs, not outputs, so pipes would not be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

**DecimalPipe**

DecimalPipe is an angular Pipe API and belongs to CommonModule. DecimalPipe is used to format a number as decimal number according to locale rules. It uses number keyword with pipe operator. Find the syntax.

```
number_expression | number[:digitInfo]
```

Finally we get a decimal number as text. Find the description. 
number_expression: An angular expression that will give output a number. 
number : A pipe keyword that is used with pipe operator. 
digitInfo : It defines number format.

Now we will understand how to use digitInfo. The syntax for digitInfo is as follows.

```
{minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}
```

Find the description.

```
minIntegerDigits : Minimum number of integer digits. Default is 1. 
minFractionDigits : Minimum number of fraction digits. Default is 0. 
maxFractionDigits : Maximum number of fraction digits. Default is 3.
```